# Como uma tabela temporária em um banco relacional pode trazer mais performance?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

#### Como uma tabela temporária pode trazer mais performance para gerar, por exemplo, um relatório?

Vejo que para geração de vários tipos de relatórios são usadas tabelas temporárias em bancos relacionais. Mas qual a vantagem nisso?

Entendo que os dados são reduzidos ali e que há os índices, as consultas são otimizadas por isso. Mas, de qualquer forma, tem o tempo necessário pra fazer os inserts nessa tabela com os dados de várias tabelas "permanentes" e se são necessários esses inserts, **vai ter sido necessário fazer a consulta anteriormente nas tabelas originais**.

Onde está o ganho de performance? Por que não é mais rápido consultar diretamente nas tabelas originais?

Comment: Segundo Janis Griffin Diretora da Oracle, *"...tabelas temporárias são armazenadas na memória, elas são significativamente mais rápidas do que as tabelas baseadas em disco. Consequentemente, elas podem ser usadas ​​efetivamente como áreas de armazenamento intermediárias, para acelerar a execução de consultas, ajudando a dividir consultas complexas em componentes mais simples ou como um substituto para subquery e suporte a joins...."*

Comment: [OLAP vs. OLTP](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/compare/the-difference-between-olap-and-oltp/)